# number validation for textbox

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate the text box should allow only numbers and only can type two digit.
For example EIN (employee identification number) has only 2 digit and check the typed value is number.
I write code for number validation.I have to allow to type only 2 digits.
I attached code for number validation

```
  var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    function IsNumeric1(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        document.getElementById("error1").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a regex for this, like `\d{2}` or if you want to catch at the keydown, `\d{1,2}`

Comment: For only including 2 digits, you can set it in the textbox as `Maxlength=2` and for allowing only numbers you can do something like this `/^[0-9]*$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.!

For only including 2 digits, you can set it in the textbox as `Maxlength=2` and for allowing only numbers.

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2n2Lsvv/7/) here

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (isNaN(parseInt($("#numb").val()))){
    alert('It must be numbers');
    return false;
}
```

& add:

`<input type="text" maxlength=2 id="numb">`

See, if that works.

Answer (score 1):

With simple javascript and `RegExp`:

```js
var onlyDigits = function(box) {
  box.value = box.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); //replace all other than digit
};
```

```html
EIN
<input type='text' onkeypress='onlyDigits(this)' onkeyup='onlyDigits(this)' maxlength='2' />
<br/>Only Digit
<input type='text' onkeypress='onlyDigits(this)' onkeyup='onlyDigits(this)' />
```